# Does Linux guest on Windows Home host can use os.fork()?

Tags: python, windows, fork, celery, vmware

I'm using VMware Workstation 12 Player to guest Ubuntu 16, on Windows 10 Home host.

It seems that software stack (python celery) i use, uses os.fork() and hangs on execution indefinitely. When i use `gevent` for `--pool` option i works correctly.

So my question is, does Windows without os.fork limits guest operating systems?
Or is  Vmware mangling something ([since it should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320605/does-a-type-2-virtual-host-suffer-the-same-limitations-as-the-host-os)) or something else is happening?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using different VM?

Comment: @gonczor i will try on different Vmware vm and  on VirtualBox and see if it will help.

Comment: Try and share results. Unfortunatelly I do not have any access to windows machines, so I won't be able to check it.

Comment: You wouldn't be running anything at all if `fork` didn't work. It's the normal way to create a new process in Unix systems.